# PhantomJS Lynx SpiderMonkey

Tags: javascript, html

I tried using phantomjs to load a website

```
http://kissanime.com/Anime/Flag/Episode-001
```

But this website have some block even if I use phantomjs useragent as mozilla firefox, then I try using lynx browser but its unable to render javascript in the page, thus I decided to use SpiderMonkey which said to be able to render webpage with javascript and act as a browser.

But how to use SpiderMonkey to curl the site and output the content as 1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://slimerjs.org it's a Phantomjs port on Gecko.

Comment: I need command line linux browser, slimjs and firefox doesnt work with me as I got no display